# Duration of animation decreases as window is shrunk

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, responsive-design

Why is it that even though I have this animation's duration set to 2 seconds, shrinking the window results in there being a greater delay at first, and a faster animation?

See [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/bQURuGbeH8#).

JS:

```
function animateit() {

$('.wrapper .water').animate({
    'height': '350px',
    'top': 0
}, 2000, function () {
    $('.wrapper .water').animate({
        'height': 0,
        'top': '350px'
    }, 2000, animateit);
});

}

animateit();
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
position: relative;
height:auto;
width: 100%;
max-width: 350px;
overflow:hidden;
}
.img-responsive {
display: block;
width: 100% \9;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
.glass {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
z-index:5;
}
.hide-image {
display: block;
opacity: 0;
width: 100%;
}
.water {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
right: 0;
top:350px;
background-color:#67d9ff;
height:0px;
display:block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="hide-image" src="http://www.videsignz.com/testing/images/water-front2.png">
  <img class="glass img-responsive" src="http://www.videsignz.com/testing/images/water-front2.png">
   <div class="water"></div>
</div>
```

I noticed that for the second part of the animation's JS, changing 'top': '350px' to 'top': '100%' caused the it's duration to be relatively consistent regardless of window size, but applying that code to the filling of the glass doesn't yield the same result - and it also alters the animation in normal view nonetheless.

Comment: I didn't get out my stopwatch, but when I tried your demo the animation didn't seem to change speed as I resized my browser (Chrome). Though if the window is short enough part of the animation is happening off the bottom where you can't see it...